# Is it possible to give style to exceptions messages in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, ide

I want to know if there's some way to add style like: **bold**, *italic*, underline etc. to the exception pop-up in Visual Studio.

E.g:

```
string keyword = "important stuff";
string anotherKeyword = "other important stuff";

throw new Exception($"My exception message with that important keyword: **{keyword}** and that other important keyword: *{anotherKeyword}*.");
```

What will give us this style:

"My exception message with that important keyword: **important stuff** and that other important keyword: *other important stuff*."

[image: Exception message pop-up in Visual Studio]

I think it might improve a lot the readability.

I'm also curious if it is possible in other IDEs, with a plugin maybe ?

What do you think ?

Comment: Most of time software will run without being debugged on the customers PC. What you want to change is purely developer tool. I doubt anyone need those *improvements*, as looking at exception text may be less than 1% of time needed to fix the bug. Instead you better *style* how unhandled exceptions of the software are displayed in the field to the user.

Comment: I disagree, I worked on a framework, and some of the custom exceptions messages are extremely useful for the developers using this framework. I'm sure that if we add decoration to important information, it will improve the readability, and save some headache.

Comment: And yes it's purely developer tool.